# Detect incoming ssh connection

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, push

I'm working on a network with many Linux machines. 
In one of them I have a file that I suspect was pushed by another machine. 
The machines can access each other using ssh connections. 
Is there anyway I can tell which machine pushed the file?

I tried looking for ssh logs but the `/var/log/secure/` directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your distro, you can check following files from your distro.

`/var/log/secure`
`/var/log/auth.log`
`/var/log/syslog` 
`/var/log/daemon.log`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the distro and your logging settings, you may have some luck with /log/auth.
Try `grep sshd /var/log/auth.log`